# How does one find the ClearCase registry server name for a view?

Tags: clearcase

I want to use the cleartool lsview -quick command but it requires a host name argument, also called a "registry server".  Can one use a cleartool command or examine a client log file to determine which host/registry server a given view is using?

Answer (score 1):

I should have looked harder.  The answer is `cleartool hostinfo -long` which will include the Registry host in the output listing.

Answer (score 1):

`cleartool hostinfo` is not ideal, because not always meant to be parsed (on Unix for instance, [it can be truncated](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21298510))

On Windows, I would prefer fetching that information directly from the registry, which should be under `HKLM\Software\Atria\ClearCase\CurrentVersion` - (I'll check tomorrow)

```
 reg query HKLM\Software\Atria\ClearCase\CurrentVersion -v AtriaRegy
```

(a bit like when you have to [manually switch registry server](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=231648))