# upgrading clearcase 7.0 to 8.0

Tags: upgrade, clearcase

I am in process of upgrading ClearCase 7.0 from old machines (windows 2003) to ClearCase8.0 new machines(with windows 2012).

What would be the best way to do it so that in case we run into failures, we go back to 7.0 in old machines? Clients will still be at ClearCase 7.0.

To be clearer, a ClearCase architecture involves:

- a vob server
- a view server
- a registry server
- a icense server

[image: http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/dynaweb_docs/0630/SGI_Admin/books/ClrC_AG/sgi_html/figures/ch18-4.gif]

I need to know what needs to restored/preserved in order to facilitate a rollback in case of issues during the upgrade process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way which can allow an easy rollback is to make sure to make a [separate registry server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/c_rgy_admin.htm) between CC7 and CC8, instead of upgrading the existing one.
And register the moved VOB in the new registry server, as part of the process described in "[Moving Vob](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/c_mvvob.htm?lang=en)".

You can then ask the CC clients to points to the new [registry server (for CC8)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/c_rgy_admin.htm?lang=en), checking with the [registry client list](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/c_rgy_client_list.htm?lang=en) to check which to determine which Rational® ClearCase® hosts are clients of a specific registry server (and check if all your clients have switched or not).
A [client can see which registry server he/she uses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7864492/6309).

I would also recommend for the client to create new views once they refer to the new registry server, instead of [trying to move the old ones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14564691/6309).
That way, in case of rollback, they would still have their CC7 views.

Comment: thanks a lot. not sure why my question is put on hold. is it unclear since you have answered it well?

Comment: @user2636464 I am sorry for the unhold: I will edit your question to add more details.

Comment: @user2636464 I have updated your question to hopefully make it clearer.